# rijndael encryptor valid byte sizes

Tags: c#, byte, rijndael

I have the following code:

```
var symmetricKey = Rijndael.Create().CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
```

key and iv are the same length, and they are byte arrays of length 32.
In runtime, this snippet fails, saying the length isn't supported.
I also tried with 16. doesn't work either.

Am I using this wrong? what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work correctly if you set the IV to 16 bytes, matching Rijndael's default block size.

(Either that or change the `BlockSize` itself to be compatible with the size of your IV.)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work as an example:

```
        byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
        byte[] iv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

        byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };   

        using (var symmetrickey = Rijndael.Create().CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
        {
            using (Stream f = File.Create("anencryptedfile.bin"))
            {
                using (Stream c = new CryptoStream(f, symmetrickey, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    c.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```